# How does "doit falloir" compare to "faut" or "doit" as a phrase of hypothesis?

Tags: sens

> {My colleague said}: Elle voulait de l’aide. Et pour que quelqu’un têtue comme elle demande de l’aide, il **doit falloir** que cette tâche soit éreintante !

Here, both "doit" and "falloir" are used for hypothesis and speculation. How does "doit falloir" compare to the following two?

> {vs}: Et pour que quelqu’un têtue comme elle demande de l’aide,  il **faut** que cette tâche soit éreintante !
>
> {vs}: Et pour que quelqu’un têtue comme elle demande de l’aide, cette tâche **doit** être éreintante !

I wonder if you can place an emphasis with "doit falloir", compared to when using either of the two?

Comment: P.S. Does the gender of this person change mid-sentence by any chance? :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes, she underwent gender transformation surgery mid-sentence. ;)

Comment: Ah, that's better. :) "Not that there's anything wrong with that!"

Comment: "faut" or "doit" used separately in these exemples are meant to describe an obligation, "doit falloir" is for strong speculation

Comment: Why *têtue*? The modified noun seems to be *quelqu'un*.

Answer (score 1):

Quelques réflexions autour de ce problème intéressant. 
(I) "Pour" la première formulation proposée: "Devoir" exprime "une obligation posée comme directive, une recommandation, une **hypothèse** ou un objectif" ou bien "une obligation imposée par les circonstances extérieures" (Oxford-Hachette FE EF 1997 p. 253) tandis que "falloir" (impersonnel: il faut) exprime nécessité par autorité, conseil etc. (id. p. 342), mais en soi pas l'hypothèse (dans "il faudrait" la nuance éventuelle de l'hypothèse vient de la terminaison [du conditionnel], pas de la racine du verbe). Dans la première phrase c'est donc "doit" qui exprime l'hypothèse, "falloir" qui exprime la nécessité logique selon un argument qui n'est pourtant pas cent pourcent inéluctable: (a) étant têtue elle ne demande de l'aide que rarement; (b) elle a, en effet, demandé de l'aide; (c) ergo, la tâche était éreintante (sauf s'il y a des autres conditions inconnues: hypothèse exprimée ici surtout par devoir -- mais ce qui aurait pu être exprimé, de façon plus modeste, par falloir + subj. seul). 
(II) "Contre" la première formulation proposée: La différence entre "doit falloir ... soit" et "faut ... soit" est à la fin surtout rhétorique, la première expression souligne plus explicitement, pour ne pas dire: pléonastiquement, le caractère hypothétique de la déclaration (et de l'argument sousjacent); la deuxième expression indique elle aussi, mais de façon plus modeste, que l'argument reste hypothétique.

Answer (score 0):

"*Here, both "doit" and "falloir" are used for hypothesis and speculation.*"

I believe your assumption is wrong here, hence your interrogation.

The verb *devoir* is indeed used to imply speculation, as in *Ça doit être prêt* which translates to *It might be ready*.
On the other hand, *falloir* marks a form of certitude.

In your situation, while the verb *falloir* by itself wouldn't have meants what your colleague canted to say, *devoir* would have been enough as it would have marked the hypothesis, the addition of *falloir* added a directness in the sentence meant to emphase the link between the observation and the supposed cause. Without it, her sentence would have been **too** speculative compared to what she was trying to convey.

It's all about balancing the *nuances*.

Answer (score 0):

« Il doit falloir que cette tâche soit éreintante » ne me semble pas correct. Je dirais plutôt « Cette tâche doit être éreintante », dans ce cas, « doit » exprime une forte probabilité : « Mon téléphone s'est éteint, sa batterie doit être vide » (je suppose, mais je suis presque sûr que sa batterie est vide). « Il faut que cette tâche soit éreintante » est aussi correct et compréhensible, mais signifie « pour que quelqu'un de têtu comme elle demande de l'aide, il faut absolument (pas de place au doute, aucune incertitude) que cette tâche soit difficile ».

Concernant « doit falloir », cela signifie « il y a une forte probabilité qu'il faille ». Son sens est proche de « il faudrait » : « pour résoudre l'équation 2, il faudrait d'abord réfléchir à la première » ~ « pour résoudre l'équation 2, il doit falloir commencer par réfléchir à la première ».